# Problema al crear una Foreign Key en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una base de datos con dos tablas, las cuales van unidas por una foreign key pero me tira un error al crear la tabla DEPARTAMENTO.

```
create table EMPLEADO(
codigo_c varchar(20) primary key,
nombre varchar(30) not null,
edad int(2) not null,
oficio varchar(15) not null,
dir varchar(15) not null,
fecha_alt varchar(15) not null,
salario int(7) not null,
comision int(5) not null,
depto_no int(3) not null
);

create table DEPARTAMENTO(
depto_num int(3) primary key,
nombre_depto varchar(20) not null,
localizacion varchar(15) not null,
foreign key (depto_num) references EMPLEADO(depto_no)
);
```

Me da este error.

*Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'departamento_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'empleado'*

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecerìa bastante :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada te recomiendo, como buena práctica, colocar en plural los nombres de tablas, quedarían como "EMPLEADOS" y "DEPARTAMENTOS".

Por otro lado creo que la relación entre las tablas está mal planteada, la clave foránea tendría que ser `depto_no` referenciada a `depto_num` (la PK de la tabla DEPARTAMENTO), ya que:  un **empleado** tiene **un departamento** y un **departamento** puede albergar a **varios empleados** (es un esquema  el cual me suena mas lógico y soluciona el problema). Es la famosa relación 1 -> varios.

Así quedaría:

```
    create table DEPARTAMENTOS(
    depto_num int(3) primary key,
    nombre_depto varchar(20) not null,
    localizacion varchar(15) not null,
    );


    create table EMPLEADOS(
    codigo_c varchar(20) primary key,
    nombre varchar(30) not null,
    edad int(2) not null,
    oficio varchar(15) not null,
    dir varchar(15) not null,
    fecha_alt varchar(15) not null,
    salario int(7) not null,
    comision int(5) not null,
    depto_no int(3) not null,
     constraint fk_depto_num foreign key (depto_no) references DEPARTAMENTOS(depto_num)
    );
```

Comment: Estaria bueno agregar ademas cual es el problema que le esta pasando, que mysql necesita que el campo que sea receptor de la clave foranea, sea indexado ;)